# Why isn't this jQuery script working? I can't see anything wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm just testing out jQuery, this may be simple but I'm trying to figure out what's wrong here.

I just want the button to slightly fade.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').mouseenter({
  $('button').fadeTo('slow',1);
 }};
});
```

```css
button {
 border:2px solid #27ae60;
 border-radius:5px;
 height:50px;
 width:125px;;
 background-color:#2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  <button>Click Me</button>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're fading to an opacity of 1, which is what it currently is.

Comment: syntax error preventing anything from work even if you fixed opacity: `}};` in line 4 of script snippet should be `});`

Answer (score 2):

Your button currently has an opacity of 1, and your fade effect isn't changing that.  You've also got some errant braces.  Something like this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $('button').fadeTo('slow',0);
    });
});
```

See it working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/0Lqcnbv5/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I got your to work using the below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
 $("#button").mouseenter( function() {
  $(this).fadeTo( "slow", 0.33 );
 });
 
});
```

```css
  button {
 border:2px solid #27ae60;
 border-radius:5px;
 height:50px;
 width:125px;;
 background-color:#2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </head>
  
  <body>
    
  <button id="button">Click Me</button>

  </body>
  
</html>
```

There were a few syntax issues with the jquery